# Magento - I need a "Good" tutorial on howto create a custom contact form

Tags: php, javascript, magento

I found heaps of tutorials on Google, but none of them actually cover howto "create" the form, they all revolve around modifying an existing form(and overwrite it), rather than creating a new one by duplicating it.

Anyone know of a good tutorial that will show me how to do that?

Ideally I need to get file attachments in there too, but that'll come later :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tutorial might help you http://activecodeline.net/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system

Comment: hmm I thought it might help too.. but I have no idea what to do with the end product. :(

Comment: Website is offline :(

Answer (score -1):

First of all, while you can make a contact form itself in HTML, and add basic interaction with Javascript, you'll have to use PHP with the send email function to send the email to yourself. PHP will also be used to upload files.

I don't think there's any one perfect tutorial, as you'd generally want to read a tutorial to get the gist of how its done, then do it your way, but you could try one of the ones here: http://www.html-form-guide.com/category/email-form

Comment: I know howto create "contact forms" in general, and file uploads etc. But I dont know howto get that working inside of Magento as its not as straight forward as it sounds.